# Passkey for user not present app?

Tags: passkey

Is a passkey (plus auth code grant) a reasonable/ appropriate replacement for JWT grant flow?

I'm currently using JWT for an autonomous app (user not present).

Does passkey require web browser interaction? If so, then the answer to my question is "no" since the autonomous app does not have a web browser interface.

Comment: No, but that’s because you forgot to tell us anything regarding the security of your app, what your threat model says, and what your goal is with this change. 

On the face of it yo user talking about 2 very different things… like comparing a cargo bike with a forklift. Both can move stuff from A to B.  But you don’t compare them like that.

Comment: Does this answer your new question: https://www.google.com/search?q=Does+passkey+require+web+browser+interaction%3F